# error in Google cloud shell .customize_environment file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

when I try to add an empty script to the file `$HOME/.customize_environment`, which only contains

```
#!/bin/sh
```

without any other code, I get the error

```
Your Cloud Shell session closed before the initial prompt was displayed, which can mean that there is a problem with your ~/.bashrc file or ~/.tmux.conf file.
```

I have to remove this file to start the shell.

Comment: I'm having the same problem today even though my `~/.customize_environment` and `~/.profile` files were working fine up until now (no changes to them).

Answer (score 1):

In the last two days, I have also encountered problems logging in (same message reported above), and these were solved by renaming .customize_environment

I guess I live without it until they fix it.

Comment: It seems like they have now fixed it, mind trying it out and commenting again whether it worked or not?